# Adjusting light level in image

Tags: python, image

What I have to do is whenever it asks for the input i am suppose to put a value between 100 and -100 and within the percentage_for_white function I also have to covert the value recieved into a decimal. This value has to go into the other function called

> percentage_for_white_amount

value and with it, it has to adjust the light of this image we are assigned to do on activecodes in the "Think Like a Computer Scientist" book in the chapter that has "2- dimensional" and in the activecode 4 editor. I done all of it but when i put it together, it keeps on saying that the amount_white is not defined. I do not know what I need to do to fix so please help.

This is what I have:

```
import image
def main():
  percentage_for_white_amount()
  light_levels()

def light_levels():
  img = image.Image("luther.jpg")
  win = image.ImageWin(img.getWidth(), img.getHeight())
  img.draw(win)
  img.setDelay(1,15)   # setDelay(0) turns off animation

  for row in range(img.getHeight()):
    for col in range(img.getWidth()):
        p = img.getPixel(col, row)

        newred =  255 * amount_white + p.getRed() * (1 - amount_white)
        newgreen =  255 * amount_white + p.getGreen() * (1 - amount_white)
        newblue =  255 * amount_white + p.getBlue() * (1 - amount_white)

        if newred >= 0 and newred <= 255:
          True
        if newgreen >= 0 and newgreen <= 255:
          True
        if newblue >= 0 and newblue <= 255:
          True

        newpixel = image.Pixel(newred, newgreen, newblue)

        img.setPixel(col, row, newpixel)

        img.draw(win)
        win.exitonclick()

def percentage_for_white_amount():
    percentage_white = -200
    while percentage_white < -100 or percentage_white > 100:
        percentage_white = input("Provide the amount of white to blend in the image (values -100 and 100): ")
        percentage_white = float(percentage_white)
        percentage_white = percentage_white / 10
        return percentage_white

main()
```

I would greatly appreciate it if someone could help me find my mistake or help me figure it out!

Answer (score 0):

I see two problems with your code.

1. The `percentage_white` in the `percentage_for_white_amount()` function is a variable local to the  function, so you need to add a `global percentage_white` statement to the very beginning if the function definition.
2. The `return percentage_white` statement in the `percentage_for_white_amount()` function is indented too far making it part of the `while` loop — so it will execute at the end of the first iteration of the loop regardless of the current value of `percentage_white`.